# Is it possible two compare two fields in same IEnumerable using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

In researching this question, I found numerous answers for comparing two different lists. That is not my scenario. I have an IEnumerable of a class with several fields, and I need to filter where one field is greater than another field in the same list.

I can envision many uses for that type of comparison, but I am keeping things very simple in this example.

To give you a better context, here's a simple table made in T-SQL.

T-SQL code:

```
create table #GetMia1ASummaryBar (
    Id int not null identity(1,1),
    ShrCreditRate Float null,
    NonShrCreditRate Float null
);

insert into #GetMia1ASummaryBar(ShrCreditRate,NonShrCreditRate)
values (null,1.5),(2.5,0.75),(2,2),(1,null);

-- to see the entire table    
select * from #GetMia1ASummaryBar;

-- to filter where the first field is greater than the second
select * from #GetMia1ASummaryBar t where t.ShrCreditRate>t.NonShrCreditRate;

drop table #GetMia1ASummaryBar;
```

Using Linq, I would like to be able to do what I can do very easily in T-SQL: `select * from #GetMia1ASummaryBar t where t.ShrCreditRate>t.NonShrCreditRate;`

Along those lines, I tried this.

```
// select where first field is greater than second field
var list = repo.GetMia1ASummaryBar(campus)
           .Where(l => l.ShrCreditRate > l.NonShrCreditRate);
```

While I received no compile errors, I received no records where I should have received at least one.

So instead of this,

```
Id          ShrCreditRate          NonShrCreditRate
----------- ---------------------- ----------------------
1           NULL                   1.5
2           2.5                    0.75
3           2                      2
4           1                      NULL
```

I'd like to filter to receive this.

```
Id          ShrCreditRate          NonShrCreditRate
----------- ---------------------- ----------------------
2           2.5                    0.75
```

I'm really trying to avoid creating a separate list populated by a for-each loop, which would be a last resort. Is there a simple way to the type of Linq comparison I am trying to make.

Comment: did you check the output of `repo.GetMia1ASummaryBar(campus)`? Your query looks fine

Comment: Looks like I need to place in some more code to show more context.

Comment: Edit your code to save output of `repo.GetMia1ASummaryBar(campus)` into a variable and debug to see what that returns. It's almost certainly a problem with that method, your query is just fine.

Comment: Not sure if those null values would cause a problem or not, but it's worth a look.  Maybe `.Where(l => l.ShrCreditRate ?? 0  > l.NonShrCreditRate ?? 0)`

Comment: @FelixCastor Even if it did I would think the one real value would satisfy the predicate unless its just throwing

Comment: Yeah I'm wondering if its throwing.  Depending on where the query is actually performed this may not be bubbling up.  Especially if the `repo.GetMia1ASummaryBar` returns an `IQueriable`

Comment: Thanks @FelixCastor -- I discovered that an intermediate function was filtering out the needed results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who contributed in the comments. The short story is that this syntax is indeed valid.

```
// select where first field is greater than second field
var list = repo.GetMia1ASummaryBar(campus)
           .Where(l => l.ShrCreditRate > l.NonShrCreditRate);
```

The reason the list was empty was because of an underlying dependency with a filter on it. I uncovered this unexpected behavior in an integration test, which once more shows the value of an integration test. (My unit test didn't uncover the unexpected behavior.)